# How to give a condition along with cv2.waitKey() in python?

Tags: python

I need to capture video and stop video after 10 seconds.But when i give condition along with cv2.waitKey() video stops instantly.When i separate the condition the second condition(elapsed==10) doesn't work.My sample code is

```
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
start_time=time.time()
while(True):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  # Our operations on the frame come here
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  e_time = time.time()
  elapsed = e_time - start_time
  # Display the resulting frame
  cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) or elapsed==10:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to stop video after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `elapsed>=10`.
It's not sure your code will EXACTLY hit the `10` elapsed seconds. 
If `10.1` or `10.000000000001` seconds are elapsed your program will miss the time and never stop, because the condition will never be met.

Comment: Simple solution,I missed...Thanks